# Maximum Weight One can Use for the Workout in the Gym

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding, crossfit, physique

Without medicine (such as steroid), one cannot gain as much muscle as he/she wishes in the natural state. There is the upper limit of the maximum skeleton muscle one can gain through the workout in the gym.

Does it mean that there is also the upper limit of the power one can gain through the workout because the muscle would not grow as much as possible? For example, one may not use 100 Kilogram weight loading for the barbell bench press during his/her whole life; no matter how long he/she trains; no matter how hard he/she trains in his/her whole life.

It is correct or not?

Would anyone give me some explanations?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's probably true, be its pretty much impossible to test where the limit is.

Comment: @Ethan Thank you for the quick answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [current research](https://doi.org/10.1002/mus.25696) suggests that this indeed is the case in principle:

> Muscle growth occurs sooner than had once been hypothesized, and this adaptation is specific to the muscle group. **Furthermore, the available studies indicate that the muscle growth response will plateau, and additional growth is not likely to occur appreciably beyond this initial plateau.**

And the individual potential seems to be based [mainly on the genetic profile](https://doi.org/10.1080/02640414.2011.597773):

> One general
> conclusion from this study that will remain valid as
> more evidence is accrued is that the number of
> common genetic polymorphisms associated with
> muscular strength, their allele frequencies, and the
> resulting similarity expressed in the polygenic profile,
> appear to limit skeletal muscle strength/power
> potential in humans.

Thus, it is pretty safe to say that you can only train muscle growth and strength so far without hormonal manipulation and that this individual plateau is determined genetically.

### Possible (rather: probable) explanations:

- hormonal baseline levels of sexual hormones, as they determine anabolic processes (max growth)
- number of fast-twitch (= innervated with thicker, better isolated motoneurons) muscle fibres, which is genetically determined, as they are the main contributors to strength feats (max strength)
- thyroid gland activity as it determines the relation of catabolic and anabolic processes (max growth)
- levels of neurotransmitters in the motorcortex, as this may facilitate or hinder higher action potential rates up to physiological tetanus (max strength)

Neither of these can really be trained or influenced much. The first one is influenced primarily negatively through nutrition. The last one can be influenced by some factors like daytime and amount of sleep, though. The thyroid gland is to some extend negatively influenced by stress and hormones (mostly pregnancy and menopause tbh).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation with so many details. Now, I understand.